# Как добавить множество виджетов в QScrollArea

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Я в питоне новичек как и в PyQT5, извиняюсь если вопрос глупый: Как добавить множество виджетов (в моем случае картинок) в `QScrollArea` по возможности с `QGridLayout` как в коде:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.imageColors = QtGui.QPixmap("colors.jfif").scaled(450 , 450)
        self.imageTreeNight = QtGui.QPixmap("treeNight.jpg").scaled(450 , 450)
        self.imageAbstract = QtGui.QPixmap("abstract.jfif").scaled(450 , 450)
        self.imageWoodWall = QtGui.QPixmap("woodWall.jfif").scaled(450 , 450)
        self.imageSign = QtGui.QPixmap("sign.jpg").scaled(450 , 450)
        self.imageLeaves = QtGui.QPixmap("leaves.jpg").scaled(450 , 450)

        self.labelColors = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelTreeNight = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelAbstract = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelWoodWall = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelSign = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelLeaves = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        self.labelColors.setPixmap(self.imageColors)
        self.labelTreeNight.setPixmap(self.imageTreeNight)
        self.labelAbstract.setPixmap(self.imageAbstract)
        self.labelWoodWall.setPixmap(self.imageWoodWall)
        self.labelSign.setPixmap(self.imageSign)
        self.labelLeaves.setPixmap(self.imageLeaves)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.labelColors, 0 , 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.labelTreeNight, 0 , 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.labelAbstract, 1 , 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.labelWoodWall, 1 , 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.labelSign, 2 , 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.labelLeaves, 2 , 1)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    window = Window()
    window.setWindowTitle("Window")
    window.setFixedSize(900, 900)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно ту сетку с виджетами-картинками поместить на виджет, а его поместить в [QScrollArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html) через метод [QScrollArea:setWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#setWidget).

Пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.imageColors = QtGui.QPixmap("colors.jfif").scaled(450 , 450)
        self.imageTreeNight = QtGui.QPixmap("treeNight.jpg").scaled(450 , 450)
        self.imageAbstract = QtGui.QPixmap("abstract.jfif").scaled(450 , 450)
        self.imageWoodWall = QtGui.QPixmap("woodWall.jfif").scaled(450 , 450)
        self.imageSign = QtGui.QPixmap("sign.jpg").scaled(450 , 450)
        self.imageLeaves = QtGui.QPixmap("leaves.jpg").scaled(450 , 450)

        self.labelColors = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelTreeNight = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelAbstract = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelWoodWall = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelSign = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelLeaves = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        self.labelColors.setPixmap(self.imageColors)
        self.labelTreeNight.setPixmap(self.imageTreeNight)
        self.labelAbstract.setPixmap(self.imageAbstract)
        self.labelWoodWall.setPixmap(self.imageWoodWall)
        self.labelSign.setPixmap(self.imageSign)
        self.labelLeaves.setPixmap(self.imageLeaves)

        # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.labelColors, 0 , 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.labelTreeNight, 0 , 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.labelAbstract, 1 , 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.labelWoodWall, 1 , 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.labelSign, 2 , 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.labelLeaves, 2 , 1)

        scroll_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        scroll_widget.setLayout(layout)

        scroll_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        scroll_area.setWidget(scroll_widget)
        scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(scroll_area)
        # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

        self.setLayout(self.layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    window = Window()
    window.setWindowTitle("Window")
    window.setFixedSize(900, 900)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```